# Is there a proper way of import vector curves to Blender?

Tags: bezier-curves, svg

Can you guys help with advice to proper way of importing vector curves to Blender? What output format and editors do you use for it?

I tried SVG format with Blender 2.79 / Inkscape 0.92.3 and after all possible tweaks I still have an imperfection in Y dimension - a rectangle with 1000 mm from Inkscape became a quad with 1m, 0.99981 m, 0m dimenstions. Viewbox is 0,0 1000, 1000 in svg source code, but has a translation offset.

Another attempt was DFX format - it works perfect for scale BUT doesn't support curve segment curvature itself - it's ok only if all nodes are  "corner" type nodes (all segments are straight lines).

Thanks for advance!

UPDATE: [dfx files examples: quad (import ok), circle (error in blender, but ok in 3dsmax)](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1CHEmCIzXRNapcUaJulEfxMu1AqrwTVrD?usp=sharing)

p.s.: it seems that dfx could transfer only as poly-curve, not Bezier((.

Comment: Attach some image of DFX which is not supporting

Comment: I attached 2 dfx files: a rectangle and a circle.

Comment: If you need to change poly curve to bezier you can. In edit mode -> tools -> curve tools -> set spline type -> bezier

Comment: Yes, I can use "set spline" but it is only a workaround that is required additional clean up and tweaks. I can draw curves in Blender but wish I can use traditional tools like Inkscape or Illustrator. Tell the true I terribly miss spline toolset like 3dsmax has. It seems like Blender 2.4 has some CAD addon for curves that has cool features but it's not available for current version of Blender. DFX for poly-like-shapes is ok, for other SVG is best way but it's not perfect. And it's still unclear weather it's blender svg importer side bug or it's inkscape svg exporter one.